# Devexpress dropdown does not show selected values in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have a multiselect dropdown in html and I am using devexpress to get the values.

the code is working fine for desktop and tablates but not working in mobile devices.
I am not getting the selected values, not in the input box and not in the `_focusedItemId` as well

Below is my code
Can anybody help me with that ?

```
$("#treeBox").dxDropDownBox({
       value: [],
       valueExpr: "_id",
       displayExpr: "categoryName",
       placeholder: "Select ...",
       showClearButton: true,
       dataSource: getSourceData(["value1", "value2", "value3"], []),
       contentTemplate: function (e) {
           $treeView = $("<div>").dxTreeView({
               dataSource: e.component.getDataSource(),
               dataStructure: "plain",
               keyExpr: "_id",
               parentIdExpr: "parentId",
               selectionMode: "multiple",
               displayExpr: "categoryName",
               searchEnabled: true,
               selectNodesRecursive: true,
               showCheckBoxesMode: "normal",
               onContentReady: function (args) {
                   let component = args.component;
                   if (!ShowCategoryData.get()?.length) {
                       component.unselectAll();
                   }
               },
               onSelectionChanged: function(args) {
                   if(args.component._focusedItemId) {
                       let selectedKeys = args.component.getSelectedNodes()?.filter( item => Boolean(item));
                       const dataToInsert = selectedKeys.map( key => key.itemData)
                       ShowCategoryData.set(dataToInsert);
                       selectedKeys = args.component.getSelectedNodeKeys()
                       e.component.option("value", selectedKeys);
                   }
               }
           });

           e.component.on("valueChanged", function(args){
               treeView = $treeView.dxTreeView("instance");
               var value = args.value;
               if( value == null ) {
                   treeView.unselectAll();
               }
           });
           
           return $treeView;
       }
   });
```